# AngularJS function declaration, positioning and nesting

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS and I read you can declare function in 2 different ways (perhaps more...):

First:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.message = 'Yes';
})

myApp.controller('anotherCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.message = 'No';
})
```

Second:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp
   .controller('mainCtrl', mainCtrl)
   .controller('anotherCtrl', anotherCtrl)

function mainCtrl($scope){
    $scope.message = 'Yes';
}

function anotherCtrl($scope){
    $scope.message = 'No';
}
```

Using the first method I was able to use different files (i.e.: `controllers.js` with all the Controllers, `directives.js` with all directives, etc...).

I tried using the second method and gives error if functions are declared in different files, which make sense because they are called in one file but . On the other hand it's more readable to me as there is less nesting and so forth.

What is the difference?

Comment: Matter of taste and style; recommending https://github.com/toddmotto/angularjs-styleguide#modules for generally accepted, reasonable good practices.

Comment: The second will also work with different files, just make sure that you have included them in the correct order. So basically you should reference the files that contain the functions before the script in which you are trying to use them.

Comment: Oh WOW, so the second method is recommended...!?

Comment: Here's a more comprehensive style guide, which is also quite good: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I see... This is not the official authority I guess.. Based on the Google Angular first example approaches the first method is **shown**...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I see your deletion suggest, but mine is a question about what is the difference, not a "what would you choose?" question.

Comment: @Mr.Web: I misread the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the difference?

#### Your First Example

In the first example, you're creating the functions via function expressions as part of your calls to `myApp.controller`.

It also happens that in your example, the functions are anonymous (they don't have names), but you could make them named if you wanted (unless you need to support IE8 or IE legacy modes that equate to IE8 or earlier):

```
myApp.controller('mainCtrl', function mainCtrl($scope){
// Gives it a name -------------------^
    $scope.message = 'Yes';
});
```

*([This article](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/09/double-take.html) on my anemic little blog explains why there are issues with that on IE8 and earlier.)*

Since the functions don't have anything referring to them except whatever `.controller` hooks up, you can't use them elsewhere unless you can get references to them back from `myApp`, or if you declared a variable and assigned it within the expression making the call:

```
var mainCtrl;

// ...

myApp.controller('mainCtrl', mainCtrl = function mainCtrl($scope){
    $scope.message = 'Yes';
});

// ...you could use the `mainCtrl` variable here if you needed
// to reuse the function
```

#### Your Second Example

In the second example, you're creating the functions via function *declarations*, and then referring to those functions in your calls to `myApp.controller`. The functions have names (they're not anonymous). You could use those functions in more than one place, if it made sense to, without doing the variable thing shown above.

In your second example, you could declare the functions in separate files, but in order to use them in your call to `myApp.controller`, you need to get a reference to them somehow. There are a large number of ways you can do that, from RequireJS to SystemJS to ES2015 modules to Angular modules (I think) or any other AMD mechanism.

Comment: So I followed your advice, and maybe at this point I will switch my code to the secondo example, the thing is, is recommended to use a closure when declaring a new controller (or anything else?) like this: `(function myController(){//code})();` ?

Comment: @Gianmarco: All JavaScript functions are closures. What you have there is an inline-invoked function expression (IIFE). If you mean, you'd put all of your code defining the controller inside one, I don't know whether that's necessary in the Angular world (I don't "do" Angular). I do that in the non-Angular world, so that I avoid creating globals (in that context the IIFE is also called a "scoping function"). But with modern JS and modules (AMD stuff, or the ES2015 stuff, or -- I think -- ng modules), top-level declarations in your module aren't globals anymore, so I don't *think* you need it.